# Como acessar parametro de classe Python

Tags: python, classes, tkinter, método, gui

Bom dia amigos,

Estou fazendo uma script para uma GUI com o Tkinter para um projeto de gerador de senha. Criei inicialmente duas classe: uma que cria o container principal (myApp) e outra que cria o primeiro Frame da tela (Frame1). Agora precisa criar uma segundo Frame (Frame2) logo abaixo do top porém preciso acessar um parametro da classe Frame1 dentro da classe Frame2 e não estou conseguindo fazer.

```
from tkinter import *
from geradorSenha import *

class Frame1(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.config(text="Escolha seu tipo de senha", width=400,
                    height=100)
        self.columnconfigure(0, minsize=400)
        self.grid(row=0, padx=10)

        self.var = IntVar()

        self.Rb1 = Radiobutton(self, text="Somente letras",
                               variable=self.var, value=1)
        self.Rb1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W)

        self.Rb2 = Radiobutton(self, text="Somente números",
                               variable=self.var, value=2)
        self.Rb2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)

        self.Rb3 = Radiobutton(self, text="Letras mais números",
                               variable=self.var, value=3)
        self.Rb3.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)

        self.Rb4 = Radiobutton(self, text="Letras mais caracteres especiais",
                               variable=self.var, value=4)
        self.Rb4.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)

        self.Rb5 = Radiobutton(self, text="Letras, caracteres especiais e números",
                               variable=self.var, value=5)
        self.Rb5.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky=W)

        self.escolha_button = Button(self, text='Escolha')
        self.escolha_button.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=5)
        self.escolha_button.config(command=self.escolha)

    def escolha(self):
        return self.var.get()


class Frame2(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.config(text="Frame 2", width=200,
                    height=100)
        self.columnconfigure(1, minsize=200)
        self.etiqueta = Label(self, text=Frame1.escolha) #QUERO PEGAR O PARAMETRO DA CLASSE FRAME1 AQUI
        self.etiqueta.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.grid(row=1)


class myApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Gerador de Senhas")
        self.geometry("420x400")


myGui = myApp()
frame1 = Frame1(myGui)
frame2 = Frame2(myGui)
myGui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem duas classes Frame1 e Frame2, se você deseja acessar um parâmetro do Frame1 dentro do Frame2, nesse caso do teu código é necessário passar no momento da criação do Frame2, exemplo:

Primeiro você define que a Classe Frame2 vai receber um novo parâmetro, nesse caso com nome **parametro_que_voce_deseja**.

```
class Frame2(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, container, parametro_que_voce_deseja):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.parametro_que_voce_deseja = parametro_que_voce_deseja
        # Resto do código aqui
```

No momento da criação do Frame2, você passa o **parametro_que_voce_deseja** (do Frame1) para dentro de Frame2.

```
myGui = myApp()
frame1 = Frame1(myGui)
frame2 = Frame2(myGui, frame1.parametro_que_voce_deseja)
myGui.mainloop()
```